# YUI compressor added "get " string

Tags: javascript, minify, yui-compressor

Yuicompressor is adding a "get " string onto my javascript minified files

ie:

```
}get ,getExecuteProcessUrl:function(){var a=ERDAS.misc.getTilapiaBaseUrl()+"/executeW.do";return a}get ,cbRunStartSuccess:function(a,b){var c={interval:this.DEFAULT_INTERVAL};b.setStatus(a);b.cbSuccess(a);
```

what is causing this? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Need more info. Eg. source Javascript and how you are calling the yuicompressor command.

Comment: I'm finding YUI compressor doing the same thing to my source - I don't have a complete answer, but it looks like the compressor is inserting a 'get ' statement after closing braces '}' instead of a newline.